# contact form not working, using HTML, PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

So I am creating a website for a company that makes cakes and I have a problem with my contact form when I upload it to the web server. When I preview the website on my browser on my laptop, the javascript works find but when I run it via the web server, it doesn't work at all.
Here is my JavaScript code called forms.js:

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.forms=function(o){
        return this.each(function(){
            var th=$(this)
                ,_=th.data('forms')||{
                    errorCl:'error',
                    emptyCl:'empty',
                    invalidCl:'invalid',
                    notRequiredCl:'notRequired',
                    successCl:'success',
                    successShow:'4000',
                    mailHandlerURL:'../bat/MailHandler.php',
                    ownerEmail:'example@mail.com',
                    stripHTML:true,
                    smtpMailServer:'localhost',
                    targets:'input,textarea',
                    controls:'a[data-type=reset],a[data-type=submit]',
                    validate:true,
                    rx:{
                        ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".email":{rx:/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i,target:'input'},
                        ".phone":{rx:/^\+?(\d[\d\-\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/,target:'input'},
                        ".date":{rx:/.{2}/,target:'input'}, //^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$/
                        ".serve":{rx:/.{0}/,target:'input'},
                        ".occasion":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".flavour":{rx:/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/,target:'input'},
                        ".message":{rx:/.{5}/,target:'textarea'}
                    },
                    preFu:function(){
                        _.labels.each(function(){
                            var label=$(this),
                                inp=$(_.targets,this),
                                defVal=inp.val(),
                                trueVal=(function(){
                                            var tmp=inp.is('input')?(tmp=label.html().match(/value=['"](.+?)['"].+/),!!tmp&&!!tmp[1]&&tmp[1]):inp.html()
                                            return defVal==''?defVal:tmp
                                        })()
                            trueVal!=defVal
                                &&inp.val(defVal=trueVal||defVal)
                            label.data({defVal:defVal})                             
                            inp
                                .bind('focus',function(){
                                    inp.val()==defVal
                                        &&(inp.val(''),_.hideEmptyFu(label),label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                })
                                .bind('blur',function(){
                                    _.validateFu(label)
                                    if(_.isEmpty(label))
                                        inp.val(defVal)
                                        ,_.hideErrorFu(label.removeClass(_.invalidCl))                                          
                                })
                                .bind('keyup',function(){
                                    label.hasClass(_.invalidCl)
                                        &&_.validateFu(label)
                                })
                            label.find('.'+_.errorCl+',.'+_.emptyCl).css({display:'block'}).hide()
                        })
                        _.success=$('.'+_.successCl,_.form).hide()
                    },
                    isRequired:function(el){                            
                        return !el.hasClass(_.notRequiredCl)
                    },
                    isValid:function(el){                           
                        var ret=true
                        $.each(_.rx,function(k,d){
                            if(el.is(k))
                                ret=d.rx.test(el.find(d.target).val())                                      
                        })
                        return ret                          
                    },
                    isEmpty:function(el){
                        var tmp
                        return (tmp=el.find(_.targets).val())==''||tmp==el.data('defVal')
                    },
                    validateFu:function(el){                            
                        el.each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                                ,req=_.isRequired(th)
                                ,empty=_.isEmpty(th)
                                ,valid=_.isValid(th)                                

                            if(empty&&req)
                                _.showEmptyFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))
                            else
                                _.hideEmptyFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))

                            if(!empty)
                                if(valid)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th.removeClass(_.invalidCl))
                                else
                                    _.showErrorFu(th.addClass(_.invalidCl))                             
                        })
                    },
                    getValFromLabel:function(label){
                        var val=$('input,textarea',label).val()
                            ,defVal=label.data('defVal')                                
                        return label.length?val==defVal?'nope':val:'nope'
                    }
                    ,submitFu:function(){
                        _.validateFu(_.labels)                          
                        if(!_.form.has('.'+_.invalidCl).length)
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url:_.mailHandlerURL,
                                data:{
                                    name:_.getValFromLabel($('.name',_.form)),
                                    email:_.getValFromLabel($('.email',_.form)),
                                    phone:_.getValFromLabel($('.phone',_.form)),
                                    date:_.getValFromLabel($('.date',_.form)),
                                    serve:_.getValFromLabel($('.serve',_.form)),
                                    occasion:_.getValFromLabel($('.occasion',_.form)),
                                    flavour:_.getValFromLabel($('.flavour',_.form)),
                                    message:_.getValFromLabel($('.message',_.form)),
                                    owner_email:_.ownerEmail,
                                    stripHTML:_.stripHTML
                                },
                                success: function(){
                                    _.showFu()
                                }
                            })          
                    },
                    showFu:function(){
                        _.success.slideDown(function(){
                            setTimeout(function(){
                                _.success.slideUp()
                                _.form.trigger('reset')
                            },_.successShow)
                        })
                    },
                    controlsFu:function(){
                        $(_.controls,_.form).each(function(){
                            var th=$(this)
                            th
                                .bind('click',function(){
                                    _.form.trigger(th.data('type'))
                                    return false
                                })
                        })
                    },
                    showErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideDown()
                    },
                    hideErrorFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.errorCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    showEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideDown()
                        _.hideErrorFu(label)
                    },
                    hideEmptyFu:function(label){
                        label.find('.'+_.emptyCl).slideUp()
                    },
                    init:function(){
                        _.form=_.me                     
                        _.labels=$('label',_.form)

                        _.preFu()

                        _.controlsFu()

                        _.form
                            .bind('submit',function(){
                                if(_.validate)
                                    _.submitFu()
                                else
                                    _.form[0].submit()
                                return false
                            })
                            .bind('reset',function(){
                                _.labels.removeClass(_.invalidCl)                                   
                                _.labels.each(function(){
                                    var th=$(this)
                                    _.hideErrorFu(th)
                                    _.hideEmptyFu(th)
                                })
                            })
                        _.form.trigger('reset')
                    }
                }
            _.me||_.init(_.me=th.data({forms:_}))
            typeof o=='object'
                &&$.extend(_,o)
        })
    }
})(jQuery)
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#form').forms({
        ownerEmail:'#'
    })
})
```

Here is my PHP script called MailHandler.php:

```
<?php
    $owner_email = $_POST["owner_email"];
    $headers = 'From:' . $_POST["email"];
    $subject = 'A message from a site visitor, ' . $_POST["name"];
    $messageBody = "";

    if($_POST['name']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST["name"] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['email']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }else{
        $headers = '';
    }
    if($_POST['phone']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['date']!='nope'){     
        $messageBody .= '<p>Date cake is required: ' . $_POST['date'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['serve']!='nope'){        
        $messageBody .= '<p>To serve: ' . $_POST['serve'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['occasion']!='nope'){     
        $messageBody .= '<p>The occasion: ' . $_POST['occasion'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['flavour']!='nope'){      
        $messageBody .= '<p>Cake flavour: ' . $_POST['flavour'] . '</p>' . "\n";
        $messageBody .= '<br>' . "\n";
    }
    if($_POST['message']!='nope'){
        $messageBody .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";
    }

    if($_POST["stripHTML"] == 'true'){
        $messageBody = strip_tags($messageBody);
    }

    try{
        if(!mail($owner_email, $subject, $messageBody, $headers)){
            throw new Exception('mail failed');
        }else{
            echo 'mail sent';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage() ."\n";
    }
?>
```

And here is the form from my HTMl script called contact.html:

```
<form id="form" action="../bat/Mailhandler.php">
      <div class="success_wrapper">
      <div class="success">Contact form submitted!<br>
      <strong>We will be in touch as soon as possible.</strong> </div></div>
      <fieldset>
      <label class="name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name:"> <h1>(Your full name)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid name.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

      <label class="email">
      <input type="text" placeholder="E-mail:"> <h1>(Your email address)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid email address.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

      <label class="phone">
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Phone:"> <h1>(Your phone number)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid phone number.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

      <label class="date">
      <input type="date" placeholder="Date:"> <h1>(The date you want your cake)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a valid date.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

      <label class="serve">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Serve:"> <h1>(How many people to serve)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a number.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

      <label class="occasion">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Occasion:"> <h1>(The occasion)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not an occasion.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

     <label class="flavour">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Flavour:"> <h1>(Cake Flavour)</h1>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error error-empty">*This is not a flavour.</span><span class="empty error-empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>

     <label class="message">
      <textarea placeholder="Message:"></textarea>
      <br class="clear">
      <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span> <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span> </label>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="btns"><a data-type="reset" class="btn">clear</a><a data-type="submit" class="btn">send</a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
      </div></fieldset></form>
```

Please can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong as this does work when I run it from my laptop but doesn't when it is on a web server.

Comment: Aargh, my eyes! At least fix the indentation on your _wall of code_.

Comment: what kind of error are you facing it in your web server?  I suggest you to look in your console and see if there are errors in your js and post here.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, I just added most of the code for the relevant question, hopefully it would make people understand what is happening easier, that is why I have separated it. First is the JavaScript, second is the PHP code and the last one is the html form

Comment: It isn't the cause of your problem, but your HTML is invalid. `<h1>` cannot be a child of `<label>` .

Comment: @bcesars, an error doesn't come up onto the screen, it is just, when I run this code via my laptop (opening the .html) the javascript runs perfectly and comes up with the correct messages if I have in-putted an email which isn't valid but when I view it video the website, the javascript doesn't play and the messages does not come up when I input an error

Comment: @Dai, the <h1> is there to make the text under the text box to look nice. to view the page, you can see a preview of it here: http://www.stellion-universe.net/SophistiCake/contact/index.html

Comment: You can validate a form with significantly less code.

Comment: @JamesGedny Use CSS to alter the appearance of text, not HTML.

Comment: I am telling you too seek possible errors in your console, @JamesGedny. you won't see then in your screen. Press F12 in your browser to open dev window and choose console tab.

Comment: @slime, I don't know javascript so I downloaded one from the internet

Comment: @TheBlueDog, the errors I get is: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/SophistiCake/js/dist/jquery-migrate.min.map:1 GET http://www.stellion-universe.net/SophistiCake/js/dist/jquery-migrate.min.map 404 (Not Found)

Comment: not to give you more headache, since you write you are not good for javascript and since you use php, you could do a lot of thing in php.

Comment: I have found the problem of the Javascript, it was a silly spelling mistake... I type form with a capital F to in the HTML but the file is forms with lower case f

Comment: The only problem now is that I don't receive the emails